# How to check eloquent queries in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to check the eloquent queries to check for n+1 problems.

Im using this "Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql){
    var_dump($sql);
});" on top of web.php routes file but no query appears. It seems that is because of the version of laravel, that is laravel 5.

Do you know in this version how to properly check the eloquent queries?

Comment: What exact Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Its the Laravel 5.5.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `AppServiceProvider::boot()` ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#listening-for-query-events)):

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    var_dump($query);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but with that it seems that dont appears the expected result. WIth that code the page content dont appears it just appaers a bunch of info and new info is always being loaded, the scroll is always raising in size. With "DB::listen(function ($query) {
    $query->sql;
});" dont shows nothing.

Comment: The closure is executed for every query. The code you put in there is your choice, `var_dump($query)` is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

try this library dude https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar , you will know all of your query